# How to convert integer input to display a character

Tags: c

I want to create a c code that converts an integer input to a character.

For example:

When the user inputs 1
it assigns and outputs the letter as a
when user inputs 2
it assigns and outputs the letter as b

it will then print out the letter
""printf("%c", letter);""

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, however, I think you might want to read about the C switch statement as it allows to perform specific code based on integral input.

Comment: Characters are already integers, check the ASCII table. Try something like `printf( "%c %c", 65, 66 );` and see what happens. I believe you can follow the logic from thereon.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code. The logic is how C treats chars.

```c
int main()
{
    int num=0;
    printf("Enter a number between 1 and 26 \n");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    printf("%c",'a'-1+num);




    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On most current computers letters **A** to **Z** (and lowercase equivalents) are consecutive and sequential. When you know the value of any letter you can add `1` for the next, `2` for skipping one, ...

The value of `A` is `'A'` (or, in all the computers you have access to, `65`)... so to print an lowercase `L` do

```
putchar('a' + 11);
```

---

More examples

```
putchar('a' - 1); // prints something I don't know by heart what :)
putchar('a' + 0); // prints a
putchar('a' + 25); // prints z
putchar('a' + 26); // prints something I don't know by heart what :)

putchar('A' - 1); // prints something I don't know by heart what :)
putchar('A' + 0); // prints A
putchar('A' + 25); // prints Z
putchar('A' + 26); // prints something I don't know by heart what :)

putchar('g' - 2); // prints e
putchar('g' + 2); // prints i
```